# How to edit the form in html using edit button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

1. I create a form which allows to view the form information in a
   different page for the user to view using  "view" button and I want
   a "edit" button to edit the same details of the form by redirecting
   to the previous page. I tried using window.history.back(); it didn't
   work.

   **html file** `Index.html` - the form

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>

     <div class="container">

       <form action="result.html" method="GET">
         <h1>Send us an Enquiry?</h1>
         <h3>Fill in the Details Below</h3>
         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
         <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />

         <select name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject">Subject
           <option value="Destinations">Destinations</option>
           <option value="Pricing">Pricing</option>
           <option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
           <option value="Other">Other</option>
         </select>
         <textarea id="details" name="details" placeholder="Enter Details"></textarea>

         <input type="submit" class="btn" value="View" onclick="handleSubmit()" />
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

   **The page view the form details** `result.html`

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="result.js"></script>
     <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="container">
       <div class="box">
         <h1>
           Form Details
         </h1>
         <h2>
           Name: <span id="result-name" />


         </h2>
         <h2>Email: <span id="result-email" />
         </h2>
         <h2>
           Subject: <span id="result-subject" />


         </h2>
         <h2>Details: <span id="result-details" />
         </h2>
         <div class="action-btn">
           <div class="inner">
             <form action="" method="GET">

               <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="returnBack()" />
           </div>
           </form>
           <div class="inner">
             <form onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false;">
               <input class="btn-1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>

       </div>
     </div>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

   **The javascript file** `result.js`

   ```js
   //call function using event listener
   window.addEventListener('load',() => {    
     //create a const variable
     const params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
     const name = params.get('name');
     const email = params.get('email');
     const subject = params.get('subject');
     const details = params.get('details');

     document.getElementById("result-name").innerHTML = name;
     document.getElementById("result-email").innerHTML = email;
     document.getElementById("result-subject").innerHTML = subject;
     document.getElementById("result-details").innerHTML = details;

   })

   function returnBack(){
     window.history.back();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `type="submit"` in tag `input` is the problem. You should remove it and try again.